# What to do with the module during integration?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I calculate the integral:
$\int \frac{\ln{(x+3)}}{x+3} = \frac{1}{2} \ln^2{|x+3|}$

And I need to do a check. I get:
$\frac{1}{2} \ln^2{|x+3|} = \frac{ \ln{|x+3|} }{ |x+3| }$

And the question is: $\frac{\ln{(x+3)}}{x+3}$ and $\frac{ \ln{|x+3|} }{ |x+3| }$ differ because the first expression doesn't have a module, and the second one does. So this is not right?

Comment: If you're given $\ln(x+3)$, this implicitly means that (assuming we're working with real numbers) $x+3>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the correct integral result is

$$\int \frac{\ln{(x+3)}}{x+3} = \frac{1}{2} \ln^2(x+3)$$

not $ \frac{1}{2} \ln^2{|x+3|}$. $|x+3|$ would change the domain  valid for the integral.